# Are Elasticsearch mappings source controlled? If so, how?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-mapping

I'm new to Elasticsearch and am having trouble understanding how mappings/schema are usually maintained.

I understand that by default, mappings are generated dynamically as documents are pushed to an index. However, **in production I assume you'd configure mappings to be [explicit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping.html#_explicit_mappings).** If that's the case, **you need to use the API to create these mappings**, since it looks like Elasticsearch no longer supports [config files for mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping-conf-mappings.html).

**How is this process source typically controlled?** Are the commands made into scripts? It feels like there should be a declarative way of doing this.

I should also mention how we plan to use Elasticsearch - we deploy our application to private networks often not connected to the internet, so each deployment would have its own cluster. This makes source-controlling and automating the process of standing up a new cluster very important.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Index Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) You add it just once based on wildcard index name and it should use the mapping specified

Comment: @TheUknown - Thanks - I did not know about Index Templates. But I don't think that answers my question, since they also are added via the API. If you wanted a versioned, automated way of applying the templates or mappings, it seems you would need to put those commands into some kind of script to be checked into source control. Maybe that's how it's done - that's kind of what I'm asking I guess: how such initial mapping configurations can be made into a reusable resource

Comment: Yeah, we use TFS to version these templates and then you can write a script to be ran before rebuilding the index.